# CreatedAtRouteResult with swagger attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, attributes, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have asp.net core web api. Where one of my controller returns CreatedAtRouteResult. How can I add swagger attribute for this method.

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerResponse(400, typeof(NotFoundResult))]
[SwaggerResponse(201, typeof(CreatedAtRouteResult))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] SubscriptionDTO dto)
{
    var issuedTo = (await _tokenService.Get()).IssuedTo;
    SubscriptionDresult = await _subscriptionService.CreateAsync(dto, issuedTo.Id);
    return result == null ? (IActionResult)NotFound(): CreatedAtRoute(new {id = result.Id}, result);
}
```

Can someone explain how to set the swagger response attribute from such type?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ProduceResponseType` attribute on your method, swagger will automatically pick it up and add it to the swagger.json document.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SubscriptionDTO), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] SubscriptionDTO dto)
{
    var issuedTo = (await _tokenService.Get()).IssuedTo;
    SubscriptionDTO result = await _subscriptionService.CreateAsync(dto, issuedTo.Id);
    return result == null ? (IActionResult)NotFound(): CreatedAtRoute(new {id = result.Id}, result);
}
```

> Note that you need to specify the actual DTO type returned for each response code in `ProduceResponseType`. Use `void` for no return body.